# MySQL UPDATE function refuses to update database

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to make this code work for hours now but I can't seem to find solution. I've serached all relevant topics and tried to change the code, punctuation etc. but none of them worked for me.

The result is always "Success!" but the database update never works (checked in phpmyadmin).
I hope that you can find the error. The code is the following:

```
if(empty($_POST['nev']) || empty($_POST['orszag']) || empty($_POST['telefonszam']) || empty($_POST['iranyitoszam'])
    || empty($_POST['megye']) || empty($_POST['varos']) || empty($_POST['utca'])) {
    echo "Failure! Missing data...";
}
else {
    $nev = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nev']);
    $orszag = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['orszag']);
    $telefonszamm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telefonszam']);
    $iranyitoszam = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['iranyitoszam']);
    $megye = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['megye']);
    $varos = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['varos']);
    $utca = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['utca']);

    $shipping_query = mysql_query("UPDATE users 
        SET Name=".$nev.", Phone=".$telefonszam.", 
        Country=".$orszag.", State=".$megye.", 
        City=".$varos.", ZIP=".$iranyitoszam.", 
        Road=".$utca." 
        WHERE EmailAddress='" . $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] . "'");   

    echo "Success!";
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please don't use mysql_*; it's deprecated. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing quotes around the strings in your query.

```
$shipping_query = mysql_query("UPDATE users
SET Name='".$nev."', Phone='".$telefonszam."',
Country='".$orszag."', State='".$megye."',
City='".$varos."', ZIP='".$iranyitoszam."',
Road='".$utca."'
WHERE EmailAddress='" . $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] . "'");
```

You also no error checking on your query. So whether it succeeds or fails it will always say, "success". You need to check to see if there is a MySQL error ir rows updated before you can declare success.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that I made a really simple, yet huge mistake. It solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Name, Phone, Country etc etc seam like VARCHARs. so, it should be treated as a string.

So, query should be like.

```
"UPDATE users SET Name='".$nev."', Phone='".$telefonszam."',Country='".$orszag."', State='".$megye."',City='".$varos."', ZIP='".$iranyitoszam."',Road='".$utca."' WHERE EmailAddress='" . $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] . "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have pointed out, you're missing quotes around your string variables.

When you're MySQL queries are failing to execute, try echoing your queries while debugging to see what exactly you're sending to the database.

```
$myValue = "Green";
$mySQL = "UPDATE MyTable SET MyColor = " . $myValue;
$myQuery = mysql_query($mySQL);
echo $mySQL;
```

Spotting the error visually is much easier when the entire SQL string is assembled in one piece.

You can also copy the assembled SQL string and paste it straight into a phpmyadmin query to get debugging information from it.